# Why electron and positron annihilate would produce hadron (jet of gluon)?

Tags: electrons, standard-model, antimatter, gluons

Electron (fermion) is an elementary particle just like positron and they interact via boson which is photon, electromagnetic force. I like to know why is gluon (hadron) being emitted when electron and positron annihilated each other?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? $e$ and $\bar e$ can annihilate to produce quarks because all the particles are charged so they all couple to the EM force. The quarks can then produce gluons so you can get gluon jets in the final state. However I don't think it's possible, or least prohibitively low probability, to get just gluons in the final state.

Answer (score 1):

In layman terms, because the annihilation of the electron and the positron can produce a virtual photon which does then materialise a pair quark-antiquark. Then each of them end up producing bunches of hadrons because naked quarks cannot exist. More technically, this is the following Feynman diagram (and others but this is the dominant one).

[image]